How can an OS be POSIX-compliant without being basically UNIX?
As I understand being POSIX-compliant means being able to present an API layer that satisfy all the unix system calls.
However many of these calls assume users, files, processes, permissions, virtual memory,... in the system is structured and organised in a certain way. So to me it seems to satisfy these calls you basically end up having to be a unix OS.
So I am wondering how other OSes (like certain versions of Windows) manage to get certified as POSIX-compliant, do they:
a) end up having a totally separate subsystem (like a VM) that organises files, procesess, users ... the way UNIX organises these things, or,
b) do they map UNIX system calls to the native systems calls without for example having to create entire file systems that behave like unix file systems?
or mixture of both?


As I understand being POSIX-compliant means being able to present an API layer that satisfy all the unix system calls.

The API layer that POSIX requires isn't concerned with system calls; hence it being "an API layer".
Although parts of the traditional Unix "C standard library" API corresponded nearly 1:1 to the kernel syscalls, POSIX doesn't require that (since programs do not generally make system calls directly anyway) – it only requires that the library calls implement the desired external behavior, even if that means letting the library do some translation work. (Although for some things it definitely helps to have certain kernel functionality.)
For example, Cygwin allows POSIX-compliant software to be run on Windows by userspace translation; e.g. it provides an open() C library function that translates Unix-style path names to Windows paths (with / being mapped to C:\Cygwin or similar), implements the required /dev behavior, etc. Similarly, Wine implements much of the Win32 API layer on Linux – not as ~1:1 mappings to Linux kernel calls, but with a lot of translation done in e.g. the 'wineserver' daemon.
POSIX is also fairly minimal as things go. For example, assuming I found the right specification, it has no mention of things like /usr/bin – its only requirements are /tmp and three devices within /dev (that is, it requires /dev/null but says nothing about disk devices for example).

So I am wondering how other OSes (like certain versions of Windows) manage to get certified as POSIX-compliant, do they:
a) end up having a totally separate subsystem (like a VM) that organises files, procesess, users ... the way UNIX organises these things, or,

Windows used to have a POSIX "subsystem" which was more-or-less an API translation layer on top of the NT kernel – similar to how it already has a "Win32" subsystem that's also a translation layer on top of the real NT kernel interface. (C:\Windows isn't actually the real path that the Windows kernel uses, for example...)
If you have a Windows XP or Win7 virtual machine, this is installable as "Microsoft Subsystem For Unix (SFU)", also known as "Interix".

OK this makes sense. but take something like the unix file permission rules (read, write, execute for owner, group, all) some system calls allow you to modify these, does that mean any POSIX compliant system need to have a similar file permission system in parallel to the native one?

Not necessarily in parallel, as long as the native system has the necessary concepts. In the case of Windows, its file permission system is already more expressive than that of POSIX, so a translation of chmod() to NTFS ACLs can be implemented.

In Windows NT4/2000 posix.dll was part of standard installation. Yes, it was implementing POSIX.1, but...

Windows accepts both / and \ path separation. Cygwin doesn't have to do any translation. (c.f. the linux kernel, Wine has to do translation, because the distinction between escape character and path separator is embedded deep in the kernel)

@user165568 Are you saying that this is the only difference in paths between the two environments? Is there really no translation done from POSIX style /-rooted paths like /mnt/c/Windows to Win32 style paths like C:/Windows within Cygwin's code? Does Cygwin not translate /dev/null to \.\Device\Null and similar?

I haven't looked at the Cygwin code.  All I'm saying is that  / has been an accepted MS path separator since DOS 1.0
